# Ionic multiple keyboard buttons press to react

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic app (actually a game) and My requirement is as following:

1. There are three buttons on screen which initially the player will keep pressed
2. When a certain symbol appears on the screen he is supposed to release corresponding button (i.e. there are three buttons each for a column)

[image]

I strictly don't want to click them with mouse instead use keyboard: say <-, ^, -> buttons.

I don't know how to handle such keyboard events or specific button press in Ionic. Can someone help me?

**UPDATE:** I am using this Ionic app as a webapp in browser and not going to install on any device.

Answer (score 0):

I used Angular's ng-keyup directive as follows:

```
<div class="col" align="center">
      <input type="button" class="button button-dark startButton" ng-keyup="stopTimer()"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="col" align="center">
      <input type="button" class="button button-dark startButton" ng-keyup="testAlert($event)"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="col" align="center">
      <input type="button" class="button button-dark startButton" ng-keyup="testAlert($event)"></input>
    </div>
```